# How to process dynamic partitions in SSAS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssas, ssas-2012

How to process dynamic partitions in SSAS

Hello Everyone,

I am new to SSAS, here is my case, I have a view table i.e., dbo.table which is having data from 2016 to 2018. By using dbo.table view i created one partition named as vwTable. Now I want to get data on monthly basis using partitions. So created partitions for every month as below.

vwTable_201601, vwTable_201602, etc.,

But i am not sure how to process these partitions automatically through scheduled jobs.

Can someone please help me how to process these dynamic partitions through scheduled job.

Thanks in Advance

Chandana

Answer (score 0):

You have to use AMO assemblies within a C# script in order to add partitions dynamically, you can refer to the following article:

- [Create SQL Server Analysis Services Partitions using AMO](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2796/create-sql-server-analysis-services-partitions-using-amo/)

Or just google the following kewords *"ssas partition dynamically amo"*, there are many articles describing the process